# Why aren't all my listeners registered?

Tags: java, android

```
public interface DownloadListener {
    public void onDownloaded();
}

public class DownloadManager {

    private static DownloadManager instance;

    private DownloadListener mDownloadListener;

    public static synchronized DownloadManager getInstance(){
        if(instance == null)
            instance = new DownloadManager();
        return instance;
    }


    private DownloadManager() {
        myHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(29, 3 * 1000);
    }

    public void registerDownloadListener(DownloadListener downloadListener) {
        mDownloadListener = downloadListener;
    }

    Handler myHandler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
            if (msg.what == 29) {
                mDownloadListener.onDownloaded();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}

public class I implements DownloadListener {

    public I() {
        DownloadManager.getInstance().registerDownloadListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDownloaded() {
        Log.e("TAG", "I onDownloaded");
    }
}

public class You implements DownloadListener {

    public You() {
        DownloadManager.getInstance().registerDownloadListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDownloaded() {
        Log.e("TAG", "You onDownloaded");
    }

}

public class PATTERNSActivity extends Activity implements DownloadListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        new I();
        new You();

        DownloadManager.getInstance().registerDownloadListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDownloaded() {
        Log.e("TAG","PATTERNSActivity onDownloaded");
    }

}
```

I am expecting to get:

> I onDownloaded
>
> You onDownloaded
>
> PATTERNSActivity onDownloaded

But I am getting only:

> PATTERNSActivity onDownloaded

What could it be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You keep registered downloaders in a single instance property:

```
// Last call's downloadListener wins.
public void registerDownloadListener(DownloadListener downloadListener) {
    mDownloadListener = downloadListener;
}
```

The last one registered is the activity's:

```
new I();   // First set singleton's property to an instance of I...
new You(); // ...then to an instance of You...
// ...then to the current instance.
DownloadManager.getInstance().registerDownloadListener(this);
```

---

*Edit based on your comment.*

```
public void registerDownloadListener(DownloadListener downloadListener) {
    mDownloadListeners.add(downloadListener);
}

...

public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
    if (msg.what != 29) {
        return false;
    }

    for (DownloadListener listener : mDownloadListeners) {
        listener.onDownloaded();
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I know that if I create 3 different DowmloadManager's for each of 3 objects that are listening for downloading state - all is ok. But I want to have only one DownloadManager. Is it possible or not ?

Comment: @drifter Sure; register each listener by saving it in a list. In the handler iterate over the list, calling each listener's `onDownloaded`. See edit.

Comment: So I need to use observer pattern with list of listeners to solve this problem. This is only approach for such purpose?

Comment: @drifter If you want to call multiple methods instead of just one, how else can you do it other than keeping track of *all* the methods you want to call?!

Comment: Hi i need the example related to above explanation.if u dont mind please give some sample.Thanks

Comment: @kiran Not sure what you're asking for, this answer is related to the question.

Comment: My question is how to get download item details through download listeners.If u have any example please help me,thanks.

Comment: @kiran Check out the api docs, look for a downloading example, or ask a new question :)

Answer (score 1):

In your code, this gets executed by calling mDownloadListener.onDownloaded(); in the DownloadManager class.

```
@Override
public void onDownloaded() {
    Log.e("TAG","PATTERNSActivity onDownloaded");
}
```

In don't see why the onDownloaded methods of the I and YOU class should be executed, they're never called. Only the OnDownloaded method of your Listener is called.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, I think you are not using a list. You just override the value so you will always get the  last one:

```
public void registerDownloadListener(DownloadListener downloadListener) {
        mDownloadListener = downloadListener;
    }
```